# How to implement optimistic concurrency lock with EF 6?

Tags: c#, concurrency, entity-framework-6

I have a question about SQL Server, Entity Framework and Web API.

I need to manage a serial number database. To do so I created a sequence table in SQL server. I use EF6 code first.

```
public class Sequence : ITrackingDate
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long CurrentValue { get; set; }
    public long Increment { get; set; }
    public long MinimumValue { get; set; }
    public long MaximumValue { get; set; }
    public bool IsCycling { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }
}
```

ITrackingDate is used to update my CreateDate and ModifyDate in EF's DataContext. I override SaveChanges.

This should work as a sequence (like in SQL server 2012) but I want to manage it myself in a specific database because I will have to create many sequences and most of them will come with more data than what we only have in the base sequence system. One feature I need to have is the possibility to update the sequence by range.

```
var serial = context.Sequences.SingleOrDefault(y => y.Name == serialName);
                var firstValue = serial.CurrentValue + 1;
                var lastValue = serial.CurrentValue + range;
                serial.CurrentValue = lastValue;
                context.SaveChanges();
```

This code is behind a webservice so it may be possible for two requests to perform this section of code at the same time and return the same value. This needs to be prevented.

So the SaveChanges() method must also check what I'm saving was not updated by another thread after the read().

Comment: @BastienVandamme Do you **specifically** want pessimistic locking on read (which will tend to kill most databases)? Or are you comfortable with some form of optimistic concurrency?

Comment: I'm not comfortable with optimistic locking but according to documentation I just read this is what I should implement.

Comment: You only need a concurrency token, for example a RowVersion column.

Comment: I follow this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to make this safe. First note, that concurrent accesses will necessarily have to come one after the other. Optimistic concurrency would not help here.

There are two basic strategies to solve this problem:

1. Use a `RepeatableRead` transaction. This will lead to deadlocks which you can solve by retrying. Retrying is safe and is guaranteed to make progress.
2. U-lock the row as the first action in your transaction. Entity Framework cannot do this directly so you need manual SQL for that. The correct locking hints are `UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK`.